# Word that means "describing a group of people based on the action of an individual"

Tags: single-word-requests

I don't know how to better describe my question, but I have an example that may clarify. The word I'm looking for can be used for example to say "this person is xxx" when that person says "All Muslims are terrorists" because a couple people did terrorist acts.

Comment: Do you want something more specific that 'prejudiced'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"All Muslims are terrorists" does not differ in its logic from "All lawyers are thieves" or "Everyone likes chocolate." All are **over-generalisations**.

If you wish to add emotion and imply a derogatory sense, you can call such people **bigots**:

OED:

> **2. bigot** (n.) **b. In extended use: a fanatical adherent or believer; a person characterized by obstinate, intolerant, or strongly partisan beliefs.**
>
> 1992   Face June 5/2   *The way to defeat the bigots is to not let them create hate inside you.*

Comment: In many contexts, "over-generalisation" and "stereotype" are interchangeable.

Comment: Thank you, I was hesitant on using "stereotype" since it seemed a little bit wrong to use in the context of my argument. But over-generalization seems like the better option.